# Laravel 5 nested or and clause within another and clause

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I want to run this query but with **laravel query builder** I'm not getting the exactly results using orWhere and where clause

```
SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE school=6 AND ( (period=3 AND class_section=3) OR (period=4 AND teacher=17) )
```

so how can I do it with laravel query builder can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Parameter Grouping`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping) to translate your query to query builder form

```
DB::table('lectures)
    ->where('school', '=', 6)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('period', '=', 3)
                  ->where('class_section', '=', 3)
        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('period', '=', 4)
                  ->where('class_section', '=', 17)
        });
    })
    ->get();
```